# Sandcastle Error BE0073 .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, sandcastle

I am trying to generate help files using Sandcastle, locally this works find but on my build server I keep receiving the same error message:

```
SHFB: Error BE0073: A project with a different or higher framework version was 
found but that version (.NETFramework 4.5) or a suitable redirected version 
was not found
```

I have checked and I have .NET 4.5.1 installed and 4.5, my projects build without an issue on the server. It is only Sandcastle that is causing a problem.

Does anyone know the cause of this error or how I can diagnose it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5
```

Was missing on my build server. I copied it from my local machine and everything started to work.

Comment: Thanks for that!  Would have taken me forever to figure out on my own.

Comment: Hmm weird. I do have that directory on my build server, but I'm still getting this same error.

Comment: Okay I think I got it. I had removed a project that had the Nuget package for Sandcastle .Net framework. As a result, the build server couldn't find the reflection files in the packages directory.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue trying to configure VSTS.

> SHFB: Error BE0071: Unable to locate information for the project framework version '.NET Framework 4.6.1' or a suitable redirected version on this system.  See error number help topic for details.

The LastBuild.log showed that it was not finding the .NETFramework folder.

```
Finding tools...
The Sandcastle tools are located in &#39;d:\a\1\s\packages\EWSoftware.SHFB.2017.1.28.0\Tools\&#39;
The SHFBROOT system environment variable was not found.  This variable is usually created during installation and may require a reboot.  It has been defined temporarily for this process as: SHFBROOT=d:\a\1\s\packages\EWSoftware.SHFB.2017.1.28.0\Tools\
Locating components in the following folder(s):
    d:\a\1\s\Documentation\Project.Docs
    C:\ProgramData\EWSoftware\Sandcastle Help File Builder\Components and Plug-Ins\
    d:\a\1\s\packages\EWSoftware.SHFB.2017.1.28.0\Tools\
    Last step completed in 00:00:00.0360
```

I ended up setting the [Project-specific components path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMsHO.png) in the project    properties to point to the SHFB .NET Framework package and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me this message occurred after I had installed the Sandcastle Help File Builder application on our build server, but the build logs were complaining that the SHFBROOT environment variable wasn't found, but I had configured an override in the Help File Builder project which the build log said it would use instead.

```
   <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- NOTE: Update the version number in the path (YYYY.M.D.R) to match the package version -->
    <SHFBROOT Condition=" '$(SHFBROOT)' == '' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\packages\EWSoftware.SHFB.2017.1.28.0\tools\</SHFBROOT>
   </PropertyGroup>
```

The above setting didn't help me on the build server however and it was still failing (but not locally).

What did work for my case was a reboot of our build server.

A fairly obvious oversight on my part, as I expect this is somewhere in the help documentation that I may have initially missed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this related issue with running it on the build server:
[BE0071: Unable to locate information for the project framework version 'XXXX'](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/31414af7-b465-4dc3-9454-19a2d01953bc.htm)

### Cause

The build engine was unable to locate framework information for the version specified in the project's `FrameworkVersion` property. An attempt was made to redirect usage to a later version but none were found.

### Solution

This can happen if you select a framework that is not installed on the system. For example, choosing an earlier version of the Silverlight framework. If the earlier version is not found, the build engine will attempt to redirect usage to a later version of the framework if one can be found on the system. If the specified version or a later version cannot be found, you will need to install the selected or later version of the framework specified in the project on the system.

The framework assemblies are searched for in the Reference Assemblies folder (*%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework*). If you have not installed a version of Visual Studio related to the indicated framework version or the related targeting pack, the reference assemblies may not exist there. The simplest solution is to download and install the appropriate [targeting pack](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html) or copy the reference assemblies from another system that does have them.

If using the Sandcastle Help File Builder **NuGet package**, it may mean that you need to install one or more of the help file builder Reflection Data Set packages which contain the necessary files. If multiple versions of the platform package exist, install the latest release as it will cover all prior releases as well. Be sure to set the project's `Component Path` project property to the packages folder if it is not under the help file build project folder. Once installed and the component path is set, you may need to close and reopen the project in order for it to detect the newly installed files.